# Matrix multiplication with SFrame and SArray with Graphlab and/or Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, graphlab, sframe

Given a `graphlab.SArray` named `coef`:

```
+-------------+----------------+
|     name    |     value      |
+-------------+----------------+
| (intercept) | 87910.0724924  |
| sqft_living | 315.403440552  |
|   bedrooms  | -65080.2155528 |
|  bathrooms  | 6944.02019265  |
+-------------+----------------+
[4 rows x 2 columns]
```

And a `graphlab.SFrame` (shown below first 10) named `x`:

```
+-------------+----------+-----------+-------------+
| sqft_living | bedrooms | bathrooms | (intercept) |
+-------------+----------+-----------+-------------+
|    1430.0   |   3.0    |    1.0    |      1      |
|    2950.0   |   4.0    |    3.0    |      1      |
|    1710.0   |   3.0    |    2.0    |      1      |
|    2320.0   |   3.0    |    2.5    |      1      |
|    1090.0   |   3.0    |    1.0    |      1      |
|    2620.0   |   4.0    |    2.5    |      1      |
|    4220.0   |   4.0    |    2.25   |      1      |
|    2250.0   |   4.0    |    2.5    |      1      |
|    1260.0   |   3.0    |    1.75   |      1      |
|    2750.0   |   4.0    |    2.0    |      1      |
+-------------+----------+-----------+-------------+
[1000 rows x 4 columns]
```

**How do I manipulate SArray and SFrame such that the multiplication will return a single vector SArray that has the first row as computed as below?**:

```
   87910.0724924   * 1 
+    315.403440552 * 1430.0 
+ -65080.2155528   * 3.0
+   6944.02019265  * 1.0 
= 350640.36601600994
```

I've currently doing silly things converting SFrame / SArray into lists and then converting it into numpy arrays to do `np.multiply`. Even after converting into numpy arrays, it's not giving the right matrix-vector multiplication. My current attempt:

```
import numpy as np
coef # as should in SArray above.
x # as should in the SFrame above.
intercept = list(x['(intercept)'])
sqftliving =  list(x['sqft_living'])
bedrooms =  list(x['bedrooms'])
bathrooms =  list(x['bathrooms'])
x_new = np.column_stack((intercept, sqftliving, bedrooms, bathrooms))

coef_new = np.array(list(coef['value']))

np.multiply(coef_new, x_new)
```

(wrong) [out]:

```
[[  87910.07249236  451026.91998949 -195240.64665846    6944.02019265]
 [  87910.07249236  930440.14962867 -260320.86221128   20832.06057795]
 [  87910.07249236  539339.88334408 -195240.64665846   13888.0403853 ]
 ..., 
 [  87910.07249236  794816.67019127 -260320.86221128   17360.05048162]
 [  87910.07249236  728581.94767533 -260320.86221128   17360.05048162]
 [  87910.07249236  321711.50936313 -130160.43110564    5208.01514449]]
```

The output of my attempt is wrong too, it should return a single vector scalar values. There must be an easier way to do it.

**How do I manipulate SArray and SFrame such that the multiplication will return a single vector SArray that has the first row as computed as below?**

**And with `numpy` Dataframes, how should one perform the matrix-vector multiplcation?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your best bet is to convert both the SFrame and SArray to numpy arrays and use the numpy `dot` method.

```
import graphlab

sf = graphlab.SFrame({'a': [1., 2.], 'b': [3., 5.], 'c': [7., 11]})
sa = graphlab.SArray([1., 2., 3.])

X = sf.to_dataframe().values
y = sa.to_numpy()

ans = X.dot(y)
```

I'm using simpler data here than what you have, but this should work for you as well. The only complication I can see is that you have to make sure the values in your SArray are in the same order as the columns in your SFrame (in your example they *aren't*).

I think this can be done with an SFrame `apply` as well, but unless you have a lot of data, the dot product route is probably simpler.

Answer (score 2):

To manipulate SArray and SFrame to perform linear algebra operations you need first to convert them to Numpy Array. Make sure that you get right dimensions and order of columns.
(I have `coef` SArray and `features` SFrame which is exactly your `x`)

```
In [15]: coef = coef.to_numpy()
In [17]: features = features.to_numpy()
```

Now `coef` and `features` are both Numpy arrays. So now multiplying them is as easy as:

```
In [23]: prod = numpy.dot(features, coef)
In [24]: print prod

[  350640.36601601   778861.42048755   445897.34956322   641765.45839626
   243403.19622833   671306.27500907  1174215.7748441    554607.00200482
   302229.79626666   708836.7121845 ]

In [25]: prod.shape
Out[25]: (10,)
```

In Numpy `multiply()` and `*` perform element-wise multiplication. But `dot()` performs matrix multiplication which is exactly what you need.

Besides your output

```
[[  87910.07249236  451026.91998949 -195240.64665846    6944.02019265]
 [  87910.07249236  930440.14962867 -260320.86221128   20832.06057795]
 [  87910.07249236  539339.88334408 -195240.64665846   13888.0403853 ]
 ..., 
 [  87910.07249236  794816.67019127 -260320.86221128   17360.05048162]
 [  87910.07249236  728581.94767533 -260320.86221128   17360.05048162]
 [  87910.07249236  321711.50936313 -130160.43110564    5208.01514449]]
```

is half wrong. If you now sum values in each row you will get your first element of vector:

```
In [26]: 87910.07249236 + 451026.91998949 + (-195240.64665846) + 6944.02019265
Out[26]: 350640.3660160399
```

But `dot()` does all this for you, so you don't need to worry.

P.S. Are you in Machine Learning Specialization? Me too, that's why I know this :-)

Comment: ;P yeah, from coursera's university of washington courses! I did it by casting into numpy. `predictions = [np.dot(row, weights) for row in feature_matrix]`

Comment: That's also an option. Good luck with you studies :-) The course is very interesting.